# periodic rotational conditions in Fluent

Tags: fluid-mechanics, cfd

I have one question:

In Fluent, should be generated same mesh in rotational faces for creating periodic rotational conditions?

Is there a way that unmatched meshes are applied for creating periodic rotational conditions?